# How do I create an expiring singleton binding?

Tags: dependency-injection, ninject

How can I create a binding for a globally scoped singleton object whose instance expires after a certain amount of time? Once the object has expired I'd like Ninject to serve up a new instance until that instance expires, etc...

Pseudo binding to get the idea across:

```
Bind<Foo>().ToSelf()
    .InSingletonScope()
    .WithExpiration(someTimeSpan);
```

I'm not looking for that exact syntax, but rather a way to end up with the desired result. In essence it would be like using Ninject as a sliding app cache.

**Update**
The methodology that Ian suggested was correct. I just had to tweak it a little bit because using a DateTime as the context key didn't work for some reason. Here's what I ended up with:

```
var someTimeInFuture = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10); 
var fooScopeObject = new object();

Func<IContext, object> scopeCall = ctx =>
{
    if (someTimeInFuture < DateTime.Now)
    {
        someTimeInFuture = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10);
        fooScopeObject = new object();
    }

    return fooScopeObject;
};


Kernel.Bind<Foo>()
    .ToSelf()
    .InScope(scopeCall);
```

Comment: You would normally don't want to cache services, but the data those services manage. So why do you actually want to do this?

Comment: I completely understand what you are saying. This was used to get some cheap caching in a brownfield app without doing any major architectural changes... meaning we went with an anti-pattern on purpose to eek some performance out of a couple trouble spots without changing the architecture.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. That sounds like a valid reason. In the end (software) engineering is all about tradeoffs.

Comment: what is `Kernel.Bind` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are essentially defining a timed scope. You can bind using a custom scope function and return null after a period of time.

```
var someTimeInFuture = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5);
Func<IContext,object> scopeCall = ctx => DateTime.Now > someTimeInFuture ? null : someTimeInFuture;
Kernel.Bind<Foo>().ToSelf().InScope(scopeCall);
```

I am not able to test this right now, but that may work.

Comment: I think you would need Func<IContext, object> scopeCall = ctx => DateTime.Now > someTimeInFuture ? null : someTimeInFuture;

Comment: Many thanks! This was more-or-less correct, except for that the scope call didn't work correctly when returning a DateTime. Structs must not work for determining scope (my best guess).

Answer (score 2):

You can use InScope(Func scope). As the documentation states:

> Indicates that instances activated via the binding should be re-used as long as the object
>   returned by the provided callback remains alive (that is, has not been garbage collected).

You would need to implement your own custom scope which handles your scenario. A good example how to implement your own scoping is the named scope extension from

https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.namedscope